# Call to constructors without the new keyword

Tags: c++

I came across this where the member function none() calls the constructor without the new operator.
https://github.com/3rdparty/stout/blob/master/include/stout/result.hpp

I fail to understand however, how is memory allocated if new keyword is not used? Also, what is the type of the returned object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without copying the exact line that worries you I might be off target, but if your concern is code like:

```
T f() {
   return T();
}
```

That is not a call to the constructor, but rather the creation of a temporary which in this case is *value-initialized*. The memory is allocated locally in the stack (if at all, Return Value Optimization should avoid it).

Comment: If `T` has a constructor then the constructor is called on the temporary object.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That is just one of the cases of *value-initialization*, §8.5/7 *To* value-initialize *an object of type T means: if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called [...]*

Comment: Yep, I was just clarifying in case the reader took "That is not a call to the constructor" as meaning that T's constructor would not be called.

Comment: So, if I understand this right, f() returns a copy of the object (not a reference) which is essentially created by a call to the constructor and stored locally on a stack?

Comment: @ibp73: Stack or something stack-like; don't worry about that level of detail. But the constructor is certainly called. Constructors don't care where the memory is.

Comment: @ibp73: As MSalters says, don't get hang on the details. Conceptually, a *local* temporary object is created, and a copy of that is returned to the caller. In reality, the copy will most probably be elided by the compiler by creating the object (running the initialization) directly on the address of the copy.